# how to select multiple values in solr via the query string?

Tags: solr

let's say for example i need to search for a number of ids, and by looking at the solr/admin page, at the "Make a Query" input form, there is a

```
*:*
```

how am I gonna search a multiple value if it only works with one query whenever I fire the search button ?

I tried

```
id:123,413,2232,2323
```

it didn't work..but this single query, works

```
id:123
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Please check out the [SolrQuerySyntax](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-standard-query-parser.html#the-standard-query-parser) page on the Solr wiki for some examples of the query syntax for Solr.

Given your example you could query for this in a couple of ways:

1. `id:[1 TO 4]`
2. `(id:1 OR id:2 OR id:3 OR id:4)`

Comment: what if the values are different and it can't be in range like that in your example as  id:[1 TO 4] ...and the default operator is AND not OR, what to do ?

Comment: Modified second option to show how to force the OR to occur no matter what the default operator is set to.

Answer (score 30):

Solr automatically uses OR as an operator, so the shortest version would be:

```
id:(123 413 2232 2323)
```

Answer (score 12):

I would slightly modify second option to be:

```
id:(ONE OR TWO OR THREE)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are only two ways you can achieve it:

1. `id: 123 OR id:413 OR id:2232 OR id:2323`
2. `id:(123 413 2232 2323)`

Both are the same the second one is a shorthand.